# Matlab: Loop through cell array to concatenate strings

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I need to import file `Degree210B49_015.dat` and `Degree210B50_005.dat`
So, I do it with cell array like this

```
column_file_number = {'49_015' '50_005'};
for i = column_file_number 
  Name_file= strcat('Degree210B', i, '.dat'); 
  Name_file
  data(:,end+1)=importdata(Name_file); 
end
```

However, the value returned by `Name_file` is `'Degree210B49_015.dat'`. There are quotes. 
And Because of this, I can't import the data.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Try wrapping it with `char` : `importdata(char(Name_file))`.

Comment: @Divakar yeah it works! Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I think it's pretty trivial. Please make your own answer for this or delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the problem here, you need to understand how cell arrays work and how `for` loops work.
The `for` loop in the example works roughly the same as the following:

```
for index = 1:numel(column_file_number)
    i = column_file_number(index);
```

There are two ways of accessing the entries of a cell array:

1) curly brackets: `column_file_number{index}` will give you the element in location specified by `index`. If `index` is a vector containing several indices `column_file_number{index}` will return a comma separated list of the entries at `index` in the cell array. To retrieve the elements do something like `[v1,v2] = column_file_number{[1,2]}`.

2) round brackets: `column_file_number(index)` will give you a cell array containing the elements of `column_file_number` at the indices specified by `index` - even if `index` only contains one element!

In the example the `for` loop uses method 2 - that is the Name_file variable you get is a cell array of one element instead of a char element. So to solve the problem you can change line 5 to `data(:,end+1)=importdata(Name_file{1});` or change line 3 to `Name_file= ['Degree210B', i{1}, '.dat'];`.

The problem is a very simple problem, but I think it is quite common (I remember having the same problem when I first learned matlab), and understanding why the problem occurs and how to solve it is important to get fluent in matlab!